# Создание виджета на Python показывающего значения ячеек в Excel файле

Tags: python, excel, виджет

Задача такая:
Хочу создать виджет, который будет выводить на рабочий стол значения определенных ячеек из Excel файла. Если подскажите какие библиотеки лучше использовать для этого и есть ли где нибудь описание схожей решенной задачи буду очень признателен. Спасибо.

Comment: Python в принципе не предусматривает создания графического когда и его компиляции, это скриптовый язык, конечно есть способы, но для решения таких задач лучше подходят другие языки

Comment: PyQt — набор расширений графического фреймворка Qt для языка программирования Python, выполненный в виде расширения Python. PyQt работает на всех платформах, поддерживаемых Qt: Linux и другие UNIX-подобные ОС, Mac OS X и Windows.

Comment: ага спасибо. Я уже тоже нарыл библиотеку PyQt5. То что нужно.